# midjourney http request INTERACTION_APPLICATIO N_COMMAND_INVALID_VERSION

Tags: python, discord, discord.js, discord.py, httprequest

I created a Discord bot using discord.py to send HTTP requests and call slash commands of MidJourney to create images with /imagine. I found this code snippet some time ago that used to work until today.

```py
def PassPromptToSelfBot(prompt : str):
    payload ={"type":2,"application_id":"936929561302675456","guild_id":Globals.SERVER_ID,
              "channel_id":Globals.CHANNEL_ID,"session_id":"2fb980f65e5c9a77c96ca01f2c242cf6",
              "data":{"version":"1077969938624553050","id":"938956540159881230","name":"imagine","type":1,"options":[{"type":3,"name":"prompt","value":prompt}],
                      "application_command":{"id":"938956540159881230",
                                             "application_id":"936929561302675456",
                                             "version":"1077969938624553050",
                                             "default_permission":True,
                                             "default_member_permissions":None,
                                             "type":1,"nsfw":False,"name":"imagine","description":"Create images with Midjourney",
                                             "dm_permission":True,
                                             "options":[{"type":3,"name":"prompt","description":"The prompt to imagine","required":True}]},
              "attachments":[]}}
    

    header = {
        'authorization' : Globals.SALAI_TOKEN
    }
    response = requests.post("https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions",
    json = payload, headers = header)
    return response
```

However, now I'm receiving this error message: {"code": 50035, "errors": {"data": {"_errors": [{"code": "INTERACTION_APPLICATION_COMMAND_INVALID_VERSION", "message": "Dieser Befehl ist veraltet, bitte versuche es in einigen Minuten erneut."}]}}, "message": "Invalid Form Body"}

If anyone knows the updated version value or how to figure it out, I would appreciate the help. The source code repository for the snippet is available at: https://github.com/Wildric-Auric/MidJourney-Wrapper

Comment: Problem solved. The version changed from 1077969938624553050 to 1118961510123847772

Comment: A reminder: Per Midjourneys TOS any kind of automation will get your account banned.

Comment: @leoconsti how had you obtain the new version? I think it has changed another time. Thank u!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below to find the version number:

1. Launch Discord in Google Chrome web browser and press F12 to access the developer panel.
2. Interact with the Midjourney bot by running the desired command.
3. Next, go to the developer panel and click on the "Network" tab.
4. Locate the "Interactions" category and select the filtered result, also identified as "interactions".
5. When the result is selected, the header information will appear. Scroll down to the "Payload" tab on the right side.
6. Get the version information here and update the version value you used in the script with this information.

Comment: @jorge-morata-toribio you might want to check this.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise not to spend too much time working with Discord and the bot, as there are plenty of services that provide access for free. For instance, [userapi.ai](https://userapi.ai)

Also you can search for paid services. But for some reason they working more unstable. For example tnl or slashimagine (working time to time)

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: Hi! What do you mean? I just help leoconsti to use Midjourney with API. There are few services, one of them [userapi.ai](https://userapi.ai). Why i offer exactly this api? Because it covering all the methods included inpaint with mask. And has free plan